# Vuetifyjs Content Scrolling After App Bar Shrink To The Min Height

Tags: vuetify.js

is it possible to to achieve something like the attached image in vuetifyjs? I want the content to be able to scroll only after the header(app bar) shrinks to its min height. Notice that in the attached image, the content does not scroll until the header(app bar) shrink to min height.

[image]